# Getting jQuery plugin mCustomScrollbar is not a function error with Webpack setup

Tags: webpack, mcustomscrollbar

We have our frontend development environment with Gulp/jQuery and are trying to migrate it on Webpack. While running our new setup, browser is showing following console error with jquery.mCustomScrollbar plugin :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $cartList.mCustomScrollbar is not a function
```

We have tried to import it with the following ways in our main bundle, but it's still did not work:

```
// minified file
require("source/js/vendor/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js");
// and npm packages
require('../core/jquery.mousewheel.js');
require('../core/jquery.mCustomScrollbar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Though we could not find any solution but Github user swarty's comment in the following link helped us resolving the issue by commenting some code in mCustomScrollbar plugin code:

https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/371